# how to connect to custom objects of Salesforce using connector in logic app

Tags: azure, salesforce, azure-logic-apps

I have created a custom object in Salesforce and using a `Salesforce connector` I'm trying to access it.

But when I connect salesforce using the user id and password I'm unable to see custom object into `Salesforce Object Type` List?

And I add directly that name as custom value and run it throw an error as not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with the `Plural name`? As I can see that the dropdown suggestions have a plural name and not the `Object Name`. Does security settings play a role here? Does the user running the integration have enough permissions to query the custom entity? Do you need to publish settings for the custom entity?

Also this:
`Salesforce session settings can block this integration. Please ensure that setting "Lock sessions to the IP address from which they originated" is disabled.` [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/salesforce/#known-issues-and-limitations)

Comment: it was a permission issue you got it right  thanks :)